# Syntaxis questions python

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

Will my code work as expected if I do this:

```
 if a == 0 and b != 1 and b != 2:
 ...
```

or

```
 if 'a' or 'b' or 'c' in string:
 ...
 # if ('a' in string) or ('b' in string) or ('c' in string):
```

Comment: How can we know what you expect it to do? The first one is pretty straight forward, but the second one will be evaluated as `if ('a' or 'b') or ('c' in string)`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it I think

Comment: Then the answer is "no" (elaborated below)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

```
if a == 0 and b != 1 and b != 2:
```

Is the same as

```
if (a == 0) and (b != 1) and (b != 2):
```

If all 3 of those conditions are true, it'll run.

```
if 'a' or 'b' or 'c' in string:
```

Is the same as

```
if ('a') or ('b') or ('c' in string):
```

It will always run because `'a'` is truthy.

AFAIK, the only "special" case is

```
if 1 < x < 5:
```

Will work "as expected". i.e., it will check that `x` is between 1 and 5.